# Horizontal Page Animation with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a website with a horizontal page animation. Currently, I'm using a plugin I found at this site. http://manos.malihu.gr/horizontal-page-animation-to-id-with-jquery/

Here's my problem:

I decided to add more pages e.g. #c7 and #c8. I also adjusted the width of the container to 13500px to cater to the 8 pages. Right now the sliding works if you click on Content 7 and Content 8. But if you click pages 1 – 7 from Page 8, it will snap to those pages. How can i have a clean transition of pages? e.g. if you click page 4 from page 6, the transition is smooth.

I've gone through at the js files, and played around with the css but I can't seem to fix the problem I have. Hope to get some fresh pair of eyes to look into this thanks.

Hope you can help.

EDIT:
Added a link to a sample page. Try clicking on page 8 or 9. From that page, click on pages 1 -7. It has that snappy animation and the transition is not smooth.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57617407/Websites/horizontal-animate-page-to-id-jquery.html

Thanks very much.

- Hakimo

Comment: can't confirm this but I think I read somewhere limit of width is 10,000px

Comment: By default the width is 10,000px. If I add a new page, #c7 and change the width to 13,500, the transition still runs smooth. But if i add #c8 and change the width to 17,000 or above, the transition turns snappy. Not sure if I should play with the css or js :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I've investigated that. *Shortly: use more recent versions of libraries you have there.*

#### "A bit" longer explaination:

**First - what is this?** That "snappy" animation happens because on click (at animation start) it drops "left" to 0 on container immediately (whatever you select). Then it smoothly animates that "left" property to the entry you've selected (from zero). And because it has to scroll through all entries (as if the first was selected), that looks awkward. Human eye can't notice that rapid change. Debuggers are our friends.

**Next - when does that happen?** Through trial and error I've found a condition: if at animation start "left" is even less than -10000px (or maybe -11000, unsure).

**Last - why does it happen?** Answer is simple. It's a bug. Which has already been fixed.
So try updating all the scripts powering this page to more recent versions. [That's the change I found about that (clickable).](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/4eeae8b0bc789ad525e98568cffb37b04b27ae84)

How I found that:

- What if you select an entry that's already selected? Most behave like normal - stay idle. But the last ones drop to the first and then animate to themselves.
- Chrome Developer Tools work wonders (F12 in Chrome). Similar stuff: Dragonfly in Opera (Presto-based, that is 12.XX or older, in v15 it's same as in Chrome) and Firebug in Firefox.
- I've stumbled upon [this entry on jQuery bug tracker (clickable as well)](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7287), which may have information for an immediate fix, without updating. If you don't mind digging through minified JS, which is hard.
- Selecting last entries having first one active produces exactly the same effect as that "snappy animation" you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks very much. Truth be told, I actually stop working on the site. I think now I'll open it up again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine on the demo page http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/horizontal-animate-page-to-id-jquery.html (I tested with firefox 10 and chromium 22), so I suspect the problem is some conflict with other scripts in your page..

My suggestion is, try to disable as much as possible the other things that might interfere, and then (if the sliding effect works fine) re-enable them one-by-one to figure out which was responsible of the malfunctioning..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually for testing purposes I am only including the js script from the plug in. The demo page works fine but that one only has pages 1 - 6. I added pages 7,8 and 9. Page 7 works for me but page 8 and 9 has that weird transition thing. I'll edit my post to include a sample page to show you what i mean.